# Redirect a subdomain to an IP address which has a port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, hosting, digital-ocean, forwarding

I have a rails app running on `ip:3000,`

I want my subdomain to go to this ip which has a port as well.

How can I do this?

My domain is from **Godaddy**. The app with IP and Port is hosted on **Digital Ocean**'s hosting.

This is a **rails app**. So on the same IP with port 3001, I am running another app and another subdomain, I'd like to go to `ip:3001`.

When I am trying to do this in godaddy's panel, as a `a record`, It says please put correct IP address.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

DNS doesn't let you set up redirecting to an `ip:port` tuple, it only resolves domain names to IP addresses.
You should set up a webserver (like nginx) on your server and proxy all requests to the subdomain to your app listening at `ip:3001`.